How can I get a stepped effect with `mask-mode: luminance`?
I figured that if I have a mask with a black area and a white area, then the pixels corresponding to the black area become transparent, while those corresponding to the white area stay opaque.
Except that doesn't seem to happen when my mask is made up of two gradient layers.
See demo below where I have first the element without a mask, then the mask as a background, then my failed attempt at masking. If the part of the mask above the diagonal is all black, shouldn't all that part be made completely transparent by a luminance type of mask? Why the checkerboard look above the diagonal? (last panel)


body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: .5em;
    background: grey
}

.test {
    flex: 0 0 16em;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, purple, orange)
}

.mask { /*  mask as background*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(to right bottom, 
                #000 50%, #0000 0 calc(50% + .5em*sqrt(2)), #fff 0), 
        repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0% 25%, #fff 0% 50%) 
            0 0/ 2em 2em;
}

.full { /* failed  attempt at masking */
    mask: 
        linear-gradient(to right bottom, 
                #000 50%, #0000 0 calc(50% + .5em*sqrt(2)), #fff 0), 
        repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0% 25%, #fff 0% 50%) 
            0 0/ 2em 2em;
    mask-mode: luminance
}
<div class="test grad"></div>
<div class="test mask"></div>
<div class="test full"></div>



I'm sure I'm missing something, especially since the spec keeps banging on about "mask layers" (would be grand if I actually understood what's written in there even means, but it's not the case).
And yes, I know it's doable with the default alpha masking. I know I can "fix" my current result with a clip-path. I'm not looking for workarounds that aren't using luminance masking.
What I'm asking here is what is happening, what am I missing in the luminance masking case?

it looks like you are missing mask-composite, no? you see the white part of both gradients which is the intended result for me since the default composition is "add"

btw, I don't think mask-mode is useful when working with gradient. If you can achieve something with the alpha mode, you will need the exact same configuration with luminance. It's like converting "rgba" to "hsl" where the "a" will map to the "l"

@TemaniAfif Wait, I think it finally hit me... the normal composition is adding the luminance?! I thought layering worked like layering background gradients... ugh.

@TemaniAfif  Do you think it is possible to just fix the rgba and mask-composite while using alpha mode and acheive the goal? Since the top left are meant to be all masked out and bottom right are meant to be all not masked out, I can only acheive the result by using an additional layer but can't figure out how to do so with just these 2 mask layers.

@SyndRain you will need 3 gradients in all the cases. The mask-mode is irrelevant to the gradient configuration, you cannot optimize the number of gradient by changing the mode.
